# Psychological effects of mega-projects on citizens

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology

I am doing research on the mega-projects (e.g. roads, buildings, airports, rail projects, bridges and etc). Specifically, I am trying to see what kind of psychological effects mega-projects may have on the citizens? What do citizens think of them? What are their perceptions? What psychological impact it may have on citizens (particularly of developing countries)?

Are there research studies that I can consult?